# Capital Font for Label in Xamarin Forms Style Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can we set style for label in Xamarin forms to have all fonts in capital. For now I have style in App.xaml like the sample below.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
<Style x:Key="WelcomeLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Fira Sans Ultra Light" />
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is by using `IValueConverter`. I don't think there is a text capitalization property for `Label` that you can also set using `Styles`, unless you create a custom control.

If in case you're okay with `IValueConverter`, here's a link on how they do it: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42643/text-capitalization-in-the-xaml

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

A simple alternative is to use `TextTransform` property in the style:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="WelcomeLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
          <Setter Property="TextTransform" Value="Uppercase"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

PS:
Maybe at the time of the question post this property was not available.